# Blog software written in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, blogs

Does anyone know of any blog/CMS software (similar to Wordpress, but doesn't have to be as featureful, I only need basic features) written in C or in C++?

If you're about to ask "why do you need this?" - I want it for fun. I get far more enjoyment from playing with native code than with PHP and friends. I work as a PHP programmer so when I get home, I relax by writing in C or C++. The blog will be for a personal website. Oh and if nobody answers my question within a few days, I'll probably start my own C++ blog software and release for free.

Thanks :-)

**If you're going to downvote - please explain why rather than just running off. How am I to know how to improve my questions, etc, if you don't give feedback?**

Comment: maybe this will help? http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main

Comment: @Ant's because he knows more c/C++ rather than php so he wants to make blog by c/c++ programming..!

Comment: No.. I'm actually a PHP developer by profession :-) I just get far more fun out of playing with native code.

Comment: @Muu there are so many CMS available ligher then wordpress but not in c/c++ ...

Comment: @Aloush: that's a start but I'm more after a bit of software that will run (CGI presumably) rather than a framework for developing with. Thanks though.

Comment: @Mr·32: I know there are lighter ones than Wordpress, I could make my own in PHP, but I want one written in C/C++. @DownVoters: please could you explain why?

Comment: Don't understand the down votes.... it's a correct and legitimate question.

Comment: @AndreaGirardi: I thought that too :-) Perhaps I've angered people by suggesting that native code could be used for web apps :o

Comment: @Muu: Using native code for a web-site is not unique. In fact, the third largest web-site in Sweden (a classifieds site, with around 4.5 million visitors per week) is made mostly in C.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I know :-) Lots of people seem to think that they can't be used though. Facebook is kind-of written in C++ too. Well, not written in it, but it's compiled to C++.

Comment: I think this question fits better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746309/which-is-the-best-c-web-framework

Comment: @phaedrus: I'm not looking for a web framework (e.g. Zend Framework in PHP), I'm looking for blogging software (e.g. Wordpress).

Comment: A blogging software or a CMS can be made over a web framework. Web framework is just slightly lower-level and more general.

Comment: @phaedrus: I know that but ideally I'm looking for a pre-built system. If I can't find one, I'll probably go for a framework instead and build my own.

Comment: @Wimmel: No, it would not be a good question on programmers.SE. "Does anyone know a software which is ..." is no acceptable question anywhere in the SE network. "Should I write my software in ... or ..." might be slightly better, but still not constructive, I think.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: if I were asking about PHP blog software (where there are literally 100s of examples) then I totally agree. There would need to be something else to the question. However, as demonstrated by the lack of answers, that's not the case with C++ blog software and as such it is a valid question imo. Your call, anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is for example a blog running on this system.

- http://art-blog.no-ip.info/cppcms/blog

It is written entirely in C++ using CppCMS web framework.

The blog software itself is available from SVN as part of CppCMS project:

- https://cppcms.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cppcms/blog/trunk

It is used on several web sites, stable and works well.

Comment: Ah nice, I'll look into this tonight. Thanks. I'll wait a bit and see what else is suggested before choosing the answer.